# AJAX - Form Data not being sent to PHP

Tags: php, ajax, post, file-upload

I am making a form to upload files with a captcha, but ajax is not sending the Form Data.

index.html:

```
var file = _("file").files[0];

// The next two lines print the correct variables
console.log("file", file);
console.log("response", grecaptcha.getResponse());

var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append("file", file);
formdata.append("g-recaptcha-response", grecaptcha.getResponse());

var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
ajax.open("POST", "file.php");
ajax.send(formdata);
```

form:

```
<form id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <div><div id="recaptcha" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"></div></div>
    <div><input type="file" name="file" id="file" onchange="uploadFile()"></div>
</form>
```

file.php:

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
var_dump($_FILES);
?>
```

Both of which return empty arrays

Edit: Form data is still not sent with this line

```
ajax.send(new FormData(document.querySelector("form")));
```

Comment: Is your form defined in your HTML?

Comment: @Tim I added the form to the question

Answer (score 0):

Since your form exists in your HTML, you can easily construct a FormData object that contains the data from your `<form>` by passing the form element into the FormData constructor. From [Mozilla's docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects#Retrieving_a_FormData_object_from_an_HTML_form):

```
var formElement = document.querySelector("form");
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("POST", "submitform.php");
request.send(new FormData(formElement));
```

If you add an event listener to the form that fires on submit, you can reference the form with `this`.

```
document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = new FormData(this);
})
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me ;( I edited my answer with new code